# "iot_tls_connect L#143 TCP Connection Error" using basic AWS example with Raspberry Pi

Tags: tcp, raspberry-pi, aws-iot

I am very new to aws IOT. I am getting the error:

> iot_tls_connect L#143 TCP Connection Error.

I am trying to use the sample aws c code. I have replaced the header config with the config for my account. but none of the sample example go beyond this error. I am using Raspberry Pi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you have the correct certs/keys in place. Make sure the host name is just .iot.us-west-2.amazonaws.com and not https://A<...>.iot.us-west-2.amazonaws.com if you copy-paste it from the console.